# Auto scroll on table view cell to the next row does not work Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer, autoscroll

i just develop a music player streaming app recently probably using avplayer. The situation is, i have a table view with list of songs which auto play feature, where, First, user need to choose song from table view, whenever the current song end, the table view will autoscroll and highlight to the next cell. Here how i did it inside `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` delegate function:

```
let indexPosition = IndexPath(row: MusicPlayerManager.shared.latestIndex, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPosition, at: .none, animated: true)
self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPosition, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
```

where `MusicPlayerManager.shared.latestIndex` is the current cell index. And everything work well accordingly.

For your information, i have declare AVPlayer as global variable (singleton) to allow the music playing in any page (viewcontroller) as below:

```
final class MusicPlayerManager {
    static let shared = MusicPlayerManager()
    private init() { }

    var player: AVPlayer!
    var latestIndex = 0
    var playlistFrame = Playlist()
}
```

All still work well, where, i can pause, stop, play , **auto play** and others.

The situation and the problem occur when the songs is currently playing then i navigate to other **ViewControllers**, and go back to my **MusicViewController** (main vc), then, the auto scroll and highlight (select row) didnt work anymore. The player is still goes as usual without problems. The problem only on table view MusicViewController is my main viewcontroller where all the tableview and the music player are there. If i stay on the MusicViewController page without navigate to other controller, everything goes well.

To make the autoscroll work, i need to start over the flow, where i need to choose the list of music from the table view.

1. i navigate to other page using segue, where each time i going back to MusicViewController page, viewdidload() being called
2. i load all list music into tableview inside viewdidload(). Already try inside viewdidappear, but still not work
3. sorry for my bad english. Because english is not my native language. Thanks

i need to know atleast the cause of this behaviour. I try manually execute function `scrollToRow` and `selectRow` using button, it works well. It just not work automatically on code.

Comment: *"navigate to other ViewControllers, and go back to my MusicViewController"* ... and then you say *"each time i going back to MusicViewController page, viewdidload() being called"* -- however, `viewDidLoad()` should ***not*** be called when you navigate back. If it **is** being called, then you are not *navigating back* -- you must be creating a new instance of MusicViewController and navigating **to** it (which you don't want to do, and is likely the cause of the problem).

Comment: Thanks, @DonMag, i just create tableView in singleton instead of in MusicViewController, and it works.